# WhatsApp restore problem: "Unable to restore your chats from this backup. Do you want to restore your chats from an older backup?"

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore

I tried all day to move my WhatsApp from a phone to another. I had everything backed up, but when I verified on new phone, I realised that I forgot the password and the encryption key to restore from Google Drive, but it was too late to change them because I was already logged off the old phone.

So I verified again on my old phone, but the chats were already lost. So I wanted to restore chats on old phone with local backup, reset password, and then back up on Google Drive and do everything on new phone, but I get this error when I try to do the restoring.

[image]

> Unable to restore your chats from this backup. Do you want to restore your chats from an older backup?
>
> <kbd>Skip</kbd> <kbd>Restore from older</kbd>

Now, if I try to press on restore from older, I get prompted the following:

[image]

> If you previously backed up to Google Drive and want to restore it, give WhatsApp permission to check your Google accounts for backups.
>
> <kbd>Skip</kbd> <kbd>Give permission</kbd>

And when I press on give permission, I get asked to chose a Google account, and when I press on mine, it goes back to the same thing asking to give permission and it won't to something unless I press skip.

Please help.

Comment: Known bug. You cant do much.

Comment: Any Solution found?